# Kubernetes configuration step 2 CentOS 7

Tags: centos, openshift, kubernetes

From http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

(1/4) Installing kubelet and kubeadm on your hosts
.....
it's ok

```
$sudo docker -v

Docker version 1.10.3, build cb079f6-unsupported
$sudo kubeadm version
$kubeadm version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5+", GitVersion:"v1.5.0-alpha.0.1534+cf7301f16c0363-dirty", GitCommit:"cf7301f16c036363c4fdcb5d4d0c867720214598", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2016-09-27T18:10:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
$sudo systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
$sudo systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
```

it's ok again

```
$ sudo kubeadm init

<master/tokens> generated token: "15a340.9910f948879b5d99"
<master/pki> created keys and certificates in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
<util/kubeconfig> created "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
<util/kubeconfig> created "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
<master/apiclient> created API client configuration
<master/apiclient> created API client, waiting for the control plane to become ready
```

And at that place proccess stopped. 
Probably, i can'nt understand something, but RedHat OpenShift version 3 use kubernetes+docker. I tried OpenShift v3 docker version download - it was ok.

Comment: Kubernetes [issue 34695] CentOS 7 (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34695). State is "Open". Kubernetes [issue 33729] Ubuntu 16 (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33729) State is "Open".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue with a likewise setup by declaring the private ip address as localhost in the /etc/hosts file. 
Example: /etc/hosts

```
10.0.0.2  localhost
```

Then I run a problem where kubectl get nodes threw:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

This I fixed by copying the generated conf to the local kube config.

```
cp /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: Done, but no changes. Above i added two issues from  github/kubernetes. There is no clear solution for now, just workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here -:

1) In older kubeadm versions selinux blocks access at this point

2) If you are behind a proxy you will need to add the usual to the kubeadm environment -:

```
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
NO_PROXY
```

Plus, which I have not seen documented anywhere -:

```
KUBERNETES_HTTP_PROXY 
KUBERNETES_HTTPS_PROXY
KUBERNETES_NO_PROXY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .....
<master/apiclient> all control plane components are healthy after 20.585964   seconds
<master/apiclient> waiting for at least one node to register and become ready
<master/apiclient> first node is ready after 8.259447 seconds
<master/apiclient> attempting a test deployment
<master/apiclient> test deployment succeeded
<master/discovery> created essential addon: kube-discovery, waiting for it   to become ready
<master/discovery> kube-discovery is ready after 66.415198 seconds

kubeadm: I am an alpha version, my authors welcome your feedback and bug reports
kubeadm: please create an issue using      https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new
kubeadm: and make sure to mention @kubernetes/sig-cluster-lifecycle. Thank you!
```

failed creating essential kube-proxy addon [Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration]

1. Fixed. But I installed and configuregd succefully 1.2.0 version... Oh